# Bullseye pipenv and Python 3.9 issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a pipenv environment which uses Python 3.7.  Version 3.7 is unavailable by default in bullseye so I have tried upgrading to 3.8 and 3.9.5 with no success.

The virtual env fails to install RPi.gpio because of missing distutils packages, I decided to see it it works from outside the environment:

running Python and then

```
 import RPi.gpio
```

results in a module not found error.

But pip install RPi.gpio reports that the requirement is already satisfied RPi.gpio in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.

Any pointers would be appreciated on the distutils/pipenv problem or the RPi.gpio issue.

Comment: OK, I solved the issue importing from the prompt with import RPi.GPIO.  but still stuck on installing it in the pipenv environment

Comment: Decided Bullseye isn't for me, the terminals don't have borders anymore and when the mouse stopped working until I rebooted I gave up.  I have  downloaded the Buster images and all is well for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Always use `python -m venv --system-site-packages`

I realized there's a problem with venv on python3.9 of Bullseye: it stop seeing the system's installed python modules.

For example, I have some package in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ which works just fine.

But as soon as I activate a venv, this path stops being seen. Notice how after I set the venv, I suddenly can't access that module anymore:

```bash
me@pi:~ $ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import urllib3 ### THIS WORKS, SEE NEXT LINE

>>> urllib3.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py'

me@pi:~ $ source ~/venv/bin/activate
(venv) me@pi:~ $ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib3   ### THIS FAILS IMMEDIATELY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

This is because the sys.path gets bogged by the venv:

```bash
me@pi:~ $ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/me',
    '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',  ### HERE IS WHERE URLLIB3 IS
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/me/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True

me@pi:~$ source ~/venv/bin/activate
sys.path = [
    '/home/me',
    '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/home/me/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
    ### THE LOCATION OF THE SYSTEM'S PACKAGES IS GONE
]
USER_BASE: '/home/me/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

The solution is to create the `venv` with the `--system-site-packages` setting:

```bash
me@pi:~$ python -m venv --system-site-packages ~/venv
me@pi:~$ source ~/venv/bin/activate
(venv) me@pi:~$ python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/me',
    '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/home/me/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/me/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```